# BufferedWriter not writing in Java

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am trying to call a method from a different class, so it can appear in my bufferwriter. My code is below:

```
public void Deposit(double amount) {
    Bank bank = new Bank();
    ArrayList<Client> customers = bank.getCustomers(); // Gets Customer Info from Bank

    if (amount <= 0) {
        System.err.println("You can not deposit that");
        return;
    } else {
        checkInterest(0); // resets interest rates
        amount = amount + amount * interest; //Applies interest to deposited amount
        balance += amount; // Balance is == amount 

        System.out.println("You have deposited £" + amount + "Interest Rate of " + (interest * 100) + "%");
        System.out.println("You now have a balance of £" + balance);
    }

    try {
        FileWriter ac = new FileWriter("D:\\programming\\Java\\JavaBanking\\Transactions.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(ac);

        String s = String.format("You have deposited the following amount:%n" + "£" + String.valueOf(amount) + "%nIn the account number:%n" +
            getAccountNumber() + "%nAt: " + LocalDateTime.now() + "%nYour current balance is: £" + balance + "%n" + toString());

        out.write(s);
        //fw.write(t);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**BasicInfor- Client class**`

```
public class Client {
    private Object fullName;
    private Account account;

    public Client(String fullName, Account account) { // Passes in First Name and Account Type
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.fullName = fullName; // Creates Fields
        this.account = account; // Adds account to Customers
    }
}

public String BasicInfo() { //Return 
    return "FullName: " + fullName + "\n" +
        account + "Sort Code :" + SortCode();
}
```

I am trying to get the Basic Info method from the class Client appeaing in the Bufferwriter, but what happens is that it doesnt write anything it is just blank , if I take out the BasicInfo from the bufferwriter then everything is written and displays in the note perfectly but if I add it in nothing appears in the txt file.

Comment: @3kings you don't need to.

Comment: Although the buffer doesn't do anything because only one write is performed.

Comment: I would suspect the code is producing an error, which you are missing. I would step through the code in your debugger and check the contents of `s`

Comment: "I am trying to get the Basic Info method from the class Client appeaing in the Bufferwriter" what does this mean? please show us this in the code...

Comment: @Ismail Khan  please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the absolute file path your provided is correct. The issue you have is Java cannot recognize the file path you use.

**Change your file format:**

```
String path = "D:\\programming\\Java\\JavaBanking\\Transactions.txt";
path = path.replaceAll("\\", "/");
FileWriter ac = new FileWriter(path,true);
```

I tested your `BufferedWriter` & `FileWriter`, it's working.

```
public class Main{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
            FileWriter ac = new FileWriter("/Users/haifzhan/Transactions.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(ac);

            String s = String.format("You have deposited the following amount:%n" + "£" + String.valueOf(13) + "%nIn the account number:%n"+
                    1 + "%nAt: " + LocalDateTime.now() +"%nYour current balance is: £" + 333 +"%n" + "ddd" );
            System.out.println(s);

            out.write(s);
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
You have deposited the following amount:
£13
In the account number:
1
At: 2016-03-24T12:38:19.822
Your current balance is: £333
ddd
```